# How can I count a PWA app number of users

Tags: javascript, html, progressive-web-apps

I've been building a web app which will be served to users via a native webview. I have been using [This monitoring Tool](https://microanalytics.io/) to monitor visits and page views but it really does not provide the stats that I need, which is the real number of people actually using my app.

I think, If I could create a js code and serve it withing the index page of the app, so this js code can collect some **unique device "something"** and create a database with that info, so, everytime a user uses the app this same js code, or something else, could recieve that **unique device "somethig"** and compare it to the database, if it already exists is not counted as a new user as it has been counted before. But if it does not exist then it would be a new user.

I must state that the app would be hosted on a shared hosting and the webiew app will not be at Google Play but delivered to users in different ways. So, what I really need to know is:

1- Is it the logic I am using correct? Can it be done?

2- Which could be that unique device "something" other than **IMEI, phone number** or **unique device ID**?

*I know it's not the usually accepted kind of question used to post here but I do not want to dive into some coding without beeing sure it will be usefull. So, depending on the answers I would try it out in practice and reshape this question to fit the Site's guidelines.*

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: 1 - the logic seems OK. 2 - that's up to you to figure out

Comment: What you're looking for, I think, is a browser *fingerprint* -- a unique identifier for a browser. here's something I found just with a google, I'm sure there's plenty of other options out there. https://github.com/fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs

Comment: Nisala, thanks, I would check the link, but, the web app will not be seen from a web browser but from a webview app. Would browser fingerprint be useful o my actual scenario?

Comment: You'll have to try it out. I'm sure there's libraries specifically made for this sort of use case. There's a lot of stuff out there for fingerprinting; I wouldn't be worried about finding something that works if I were you.

Comment: All right. I would start for my quest right now. And be sure if I can manage to make it work I will be back and fix the question and post the answer for everybory to take benefit from it. thanks a lot.

Answer (score -2):

Most analytics libraries like Google analytics usually generate a specific ID for each user.

You're right though that it is possible. Usually you'll simply generate the ID the first time and then just store it locally, checking on every subsequent visit if it's still there, though it can dissapear if a user clears their cookies

Comment: then don't use cookies to store it - there's better storage options :p

Comment: yes, localStorage would be nice

Comment: I said cookies to keep the answer simple. Most browsers will clear localstorage at the same time as cookies. Also, not all analytics libraries use localstorage as older browsers don't support it

Comment: Also, let clarify the fact that as I am a Cuban living in Cuba I can not access Google Play to store my app, so I can not benefit from the usual Google tools, so the only way is to build my own system to monitor that.

Comment: @Bravo Ah sorry. I am indeed aware of what a PWA is. I was more referring to analytics in general and how a lot of them use cookies as a fallback for browsers that don't have access to modern APIs. Sorry